# How to configure the port to be exposed for dockerized Rasa-NLU

Tags: docker, rasa-nlu

I'm new with Rasa and docker.
My attempt to dockerize Rasa-NLU consists of the below steps:
Instructions were referred from [here](http://www.toptechpoint.com/mlai/rasa-nlu-installation-configuration)

1. Did a Git clone of latest Rasa-NLU
2. Copied `Dockerfile_full` (from within `/docker`) to the root directory
3. Changed the port number specified in `config_default.json` and `Dockerfile_full` from default(5000) to 5048.
4. Build using: `docker build -t rasa_nlu .`
5. Run the docker on a port(5048) different from the default(5000) port.

However, the following gets logged in the console:

`INFO:rasa_nlu.data_router:Logging requests to '/app/logs/rasa_nlu_log-20170928-091903-1.log'.`
`INFO:__main__:Started http server on port 5000`
`2017-09-28 09:19:03+0000 [-] Log opened.
2017-09-28 09:19:03+0000 [-] Site starting on 5000
2017-09-28 09:19:03+0000 [-] Starting factory <twisted.web.server.Site instance at 0x7fbab0bfdd40>`

If I try to hit the Rasa endpoint locally using CURL, I get a `connection reset` error. My doubts of a wrong port being referred were confirmed when checked within docker container (using `docker exec`)it was running on port 5000.

Can someone help me out here as to where exactly I'm going wrong and where should the port number be configured ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add and change port in `sample_configs/config_spacy_duckling.json` and then try

Comment: Great! @TarunLalwani it works! After going through the `Dockerfile_full` contents, I assumed it'll take the port from `config_defaults.json`. Hence I'd not explicitly set the port in `config_spacy_duckling.json` file. Point noted. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dockerfile_full expects the config file to be in the sample_configs folder. Also Dockerfile_full uses the config_spacy_duckling.json config file. So make sure you replace the below reference in the dockerfile. You can either change the config file it copies in or change the port configuration in the correct file.

`COPY sample_configs/config_spacy_duckling.json ${RASA_NLU_HOME}/config.json`

Ignoring that, why change the port in both locations? All you need to do is change it in your docker run or compose command.

`docker run -p 5048:5000 rasa/rasa_nlu:latest-full`

Answer (score 1):

Add and change port in `sample_configs/config_spacy_duckling.json`. If you see the `Dockerfile` this the config that is copied and it has no port defined. So once you put port in this and build it would work